# Javascript Values not being submitted at POST

Tags: php, javascript, post

I have a form where the user clicks various radio groups, this generates a 'score' that is calculated with javascript, and populates a textbox at the top of the form with a running total.

When the form is submitted, the POST value for this textbox is empty, so when it moves onto the output sheet there is no value to display.

All other textboxes that are manually typed in work fine.   All Names/Ids etc are correct, is there something I'm missing in order to get it to correctly retain the value generated by the JS in the POST value when the form is submitted?

This (populated from JS) doesn't work :

```
<input name="Result_AutoFail" type="text" class="ResultsBox" id="Result_AutoFail" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['Result_AutoFail']); ?>"/>
```

but this (Manually typed in) does:

```
<input name="CustName" type="text" id="CustName" size="25" maxlength="25" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['CustName']); ?>"/>
```

The JS used to populate the box is this for each question, this works fine and puts the value into the box correctly as the user clicks each radio button for each question, just doesn't send it off to POST:

```
 for (i=0;i<2;i++)
{

if (document.MonitorForm.SBI_CA027[i].checked == true)
{

    CA027Selected = document.MonitorForm.SBI_CA027[i].value

}
}


if (CA027Selected == "Yes")
{

    if (AutoFailCount == 0)
    {
        document.MonitorForm.Result_AutoFail.style.backgroundColor = "#008000";

    }
    else if (AutoFailCount >= 1)
    {

        document.MonitorForm.Result_AutoFail.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }





}
else if( CA027Selected == "No")
{
    AutoFailCount = (AutoFailCount + 1);

    if (AutoFailCount == 0)
    {
        document.MonitorForm.Result_AutoFail.style.backgroundColor = "#008000";

    }
    else if (AutoFailCount >= 1)
    {

        document.MonitorForm.Result_AutoFail.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
    }


}
```

Then is written into the textbox with:

```
document.MonitorForm.Result_AutoFail.value =  AutoFailCount ;
```

Cheers!

Comment: I really wouldn't know which code to share :)  I have   <input name="Result_AutoFail" type="text" class="ResultsBox" id="Result_AutoFail" size="2" maxlength="2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['Result_AutoFail']); ?>"/> for the results box that doesn't work, and exactly the same (with Names/ID's etc amended) for the manually inputted ones that do.

Comment: I was thinking about your JS code you use to populate the field and the way it is triggered.

Comment: @yent - edited above to show the JS, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing the result into hidden input.

```
<input type="hidden" value="some_value" name="result" id="result" />
```

Comment: I've edited the original question to show all relevant bits of code, can you make sense of it?  I don't think I need a hidden field in addition as the score does need to be visual, that all works fine, just doesn't send it to POST.

Answer (score 0):

if you dont submit it from a formfield like input or textfield it wont come in the $_POST array

if you want to submit additional data in your post you have to write them in hidden inputs

Comment: it is put into a textfield though?  have edited the original question to include it.